# Matlab cell length

Tags: matlab, timestamp

Ok I seem to have got the most of the problem solved, I just need an expert eye to pick my error as I am stuck.

I have a file of length `[125 X 27]` and I want to convert it to a file of length `[144 x 27]`.  Now, I want to replace the missing files (time stamps) rows of  zeros. (ideally its a 10 min daily average thus should have file length of 144)

Here is the code I am using:

```
fid = fopen('test.csv', 'rt');

data = textscan(fid, ['%s' repmat('%f',1,27)], 'HeaderLines', 1, 'Delimiter', ',');

fclose(fid);

%//Make time a datenum of the first column
time = datenum(data{1} , 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM')
%//Find the difference in minutes from each row

timeDiff = round(diff(datenum(time)*(24*60)))

%//the rest of the data
data = cell2mat(data(2:28));


newdata=zeros(144,27);

for n=1:length(timeDiff)

    if timeDiff(n)==10

        newdata(n,:)=data(n,:);
        newdata(n+1,:)=data(n+1,:);
    else
        p=timeDiff(n)/10
        n=n+p;

    end

end
```

Can somebody please help me to find the error inside my `for` loop. My output file seems to miss few timestamped values.

%*************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

Can somebody help me to figure out the uiget to read the above file??

i am replacing

> fid = fopen('test.csv', 'rt');
>
> data = textscan(fid, ['%s' repmat('%f',1,27)], 'HeaderLines', 1, 'Delimiter', ',');
>
> fclose(fid);

With

> [c,pathc]=uigetfile({'*.txt'},'Select the file','C:\data');
>
> file=[pathc c];
>
> file= textscan(c, ['%s' repmat('%f',1,27)], 'HeaderLines', 1, 'Delimiter', ',');

And its not working

%

---

NEW ADDITION to old question

> p = 1; %index into destination
>   for n = 1:length(timeDiff)
>   %     if timeDiff(n) == 10
>   %         newfile(p,:) = file(n,:);
>   %          newfile(p+1,:)=file(n+1,:);
>   %         p = p + 1;
>   %     else
>   %         p = p + (timeDiff(n)/10);
>   %     end
>
> q=cumsum(timeDiff(n)/10);
>   if q==1
>   newfile(p,:)=file(n,:);
>   p=p+1;
>     else
>         p = p + (timeDiff(n)/10);
>
> end
>
> end
>
> xlswrite('testnewws11.xls',newfile);

even with the cumsum command this code fails when my file has  1,2 time stamps in middle of  long missing ones
example

> 8/16/2009 0:00 5.34
>   8/16/2009 0:10 3.23
>   8/16/2009 0:20 2.23
>   8/16/2009 0:30 1.23
>   8/16/2009 0:50 70
>   8/16/2009 2:00 5.23
>   8/16/2009 2:20 544
>   8/16/2009 2:30 42.23
>   8/16/2009 3:00 71.23
>   8/16/2009 3:10 3.23

My output looks like

> 5.34
>   3.23
>   2.23
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   5.23
>   544.
>   42.23
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   3.23

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update for new version of question**

You seem to have misunderstood the intention of the `cumsum` solution I suggested.  You no longer need a loop since `cumsum` calculates the final indeces for you.  However, I left out one crucial part - the first index has to still be determined from the data file.  Replace your for loop with the following:

```
[y,m,d] = datevec(time(1)); %# get the year, month and day corresponding to the first recorded timestamp
firstidx = time(1)-datenum(y,m,d,0,0,0)+1; %# get the offset from midnight to the first recorded timestamp
q = cumsum([firstidx ; round(diff(time)*24*60)/10]); %# these are the indeces into newdata
newdata(q,:) = data;
```

**Previous answers**

You are using `n` to index both newdata and data, and stopping your indexing based on length(timeDiff).  This means that your loop will never touch elements of newData beyond length(timeDiff).    Also, I don't at all understand what the `newdata(n+1,)...` line does, since it would usually get overwritten on the next iteration anyway.  I think what you need is something like:

```
p = 1; %index into destination
for n = 1:length(timeDiff)
    if timeDiff(n) == 10
        newdata(p,:) = data(n,:);
        p = p + 1;
    else
        p = p + timeDiff(n)/10;
    end
end
```

You can make this look a little neater by doing:

```
p = cumsum(timeDiff(n)/10); % vector of destination indeces
newdata(p) = data;
```

(I didn't actually test this...)

Note that this scheme depends on the `timeDiff` vector containing integer values!  You might need to throw a call to `round` in there too.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for catching that error. I did however had to add the line
>newdata(p+1,:)=data(n+1,:);

as my timeDiff takes diff of last two numbers so if i do not add this line it misses the last data set. With this it works perfectly.
 Another related question.
 Do you know a easy way to rewrite the headers and the timestamp( 1st column) column into the newdata file?
Thanks

Comment: For the header lines, I suggest you simply use `fgetl` and `fprintf`.  Don't forget to remove the `HeaderLines` item from `textscan` though!  For copying the timestamp, can't you print `time(i)` as you print `newdata(i)`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. do you why i keep getting datenum faults on somefiles and not on all , though they have same formats.



??? Error using ==> datenum at 174
DATENUM failed.

Error in ==> makefilelength144 at 18
time = datenum(data{1} , 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM');

Caused by:
    Error using ==> dtstr2dtnummx
    Failed on converting date string to date number.

Comment: Try doing `disp(data{1})` - sometimes that helps spot subtle format differences.

Comment: I got rid of 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM' in the  
time= .... and it seems to read the default format.
Thanks

Comment: I do however have the problem with  

> newdata(p+1,:)= data(n+1,:) ; 
as when the file is smaller , my program crashes and i do not know to include the last data pt before missing timestamps

Comment: Try using the `cumsum` alternative I gave above.  I think that will automatically put the last valid timestamp in the right place.

Comment: I did not understand by reading the help of cumsum menu. So i do not know how to use that.

Comment: `cumsum` is the cumulative sum.  Imagine you had a data vector that should have had five elements, but was missing the third element.  I think `timeDiff/10` would be `[1 1 2 1]`.  `cumsum([1 1 2 1]) = [1 2 4 5]`, which tells you the correct destination indeces in `newData`.

Comment: Tried and it failed too...
Can you write the cumsum command into the above code , just to be sure i am not doing something wrong.

thanks a lot

Comment: @AP - it works in my testing, can you post an example timeDiff vector?  I'm going to be offline for the next few hours, but can get back to this later.

Comment: I do not know how to upload a full file . I can explain, the code fails at points like 3/3/2010 0:50; 3/3/2010 1:10; 3/3/2010 1:30; 3/3/2010 1:50; where i have 2 missing time stamps followed by a single time and then agian 2,3 time stamps missing. Please give me the code with cumsum command thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot mtrw.  still could not make cumsum code work. But found out the error i had . I had to  recall   newdata(p,:) = data(n,:);  after the else command to write it properly and now its working well :)

Answer (score 2):

For the second question:

Uigetfile returns a filename, not a file ID. Therefore, you still need to call fopen.

```
[c,pathc]=uigetfile({'*.txt'},'Select the file','C:\data');

file=[pathc c];

%# get a file ID
fid = fopen(file,'rt');

data= textscan(fid, ['%s' repmat('%f',1,27)], 'HeaderLines', 1, 'Delimiter', ',');

fclose(fid)
```

Comment: Sweet  , Thanks 

I still have problem on some files , it gives me error

>??? Error using ==> datenum at 174
DATENUM failed.

Error in ==> makefilelength144 at 33
time = datenum(data{1} , 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM');

Caused by:
    Error using ==> dtstr2dtnummx
    Failed on converting date string to date number.

>
When i look at file it looks the same as other file which gives no error, any thoughts??